# R.id. Cannot resolve symbol 'message'

Tags: java, android

This is the code and the error in *"Cannot resolve symbol 'message'"* on the line:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
```

The application worked well, previously. It's likely to be a stupid error.

#### File *MainActivity.java*

```
package com.example.antonio.newsbooklite2;

/**
 * Created by antonio on 30/12/16.
 */

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
//import android.support.design.widget.*;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);

        // Do something in response to button
    }
}
```

#### File *strings.xml*

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">newsbooklite2</string>

    <string name="message">Scrivi messaggio: </string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    enter code here
    <string name="nome_stringa">Testo_visualizzato</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the string from the xml?

Comment: You probably don't have an EditText with `android:id="@+id/message"` in your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: you are referring to an EditText in activity_main.xml layout but in your question I can see your string.xml code. Post your activity_main.xml code

Answer (score 0):

You might be mixing these things.

```
findViewById(R.id.message);
```

returns the View from the layout.

If you want the string, you can use:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a message id defined in the *string.xml* file in line:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
```

Change the message to the id defined in the layout file.